# QImage / Logo in QCustomPlot

Tags: c++, qt, qcustomplot

How can I add a logo/QImage in a `QCustomPlot` plot ?

I am fairly new to both Qt and `QCustomPlot`.

I am using C++

```
QCustomPlot* plot = new QCustomPlot(parent);
logo = new QImage();
bool success  = logo->load("Logo-Wallpaper.png");
```

How to add logo to plot?

Comment: Do you want the logo to be always shown for example in a corner? Or it should be placed on (x,y) position?

Comment: Want to always display the logo in a corner

Answer (score 0):

You can set the pixmap of a label by the logo image and add the label to a layout in the plot :

```
QLabel *myLabel = new QLabel(this);
myLabel->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(logo));

QGridLayout * layout = new QGridLayout(plot);
layout->setAlignment(Qt::AlignRight | Qt::AlignTop);
layout->addWidget(myLabel ,0,0);
```